# Difference between ∀x∃y and ∃y∀x

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm currently reading this document by the University of Texas in Austin about Predicate Logic, and got stuck on the following:

Note about nested quantifiers: For predicate P (x, y): ∀x∀yP (x, y) has the same meaning as ∀y∀xP (x, y). ∃x∃yP (x, y) has the same meaning as ∃y∃xP (x, y).

We can not interchange the position of ∀ and ∃ like this! 
Example: U = set of married people. True or false? 
1. ∀x∃y[x is married to y]
2. ∃y∀x[x is married to y]

I'm doubtful about the answer to this example. Also, some explanation about ordering of ∃ and ∀ operators would be appreciated.

Comment: They say 1) everyone is married to someone and 2) someone is married to everyone. Very different!

Comment: See [Confused between Nested Quantifiers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64500/confused-between-nested-quantifiers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to consider this is visually.  Imagine an $x$-$y$ grid, in which we mark a spot at $(x, y)$ if the proposition is true for that $x$ and that $y$.  Then $\forall x \exists y$ amounts to there being at least one spot in every column, and $\exists y \forall x$ amounts there to being at least one row that is completely filled in from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

The  first says: "For all $x$ it exist a $y$ such that $x$ is married to $y$."  So every $x$ is married.

The second one says: "There exist a $y$ such that for all $x$, $y$ is married to $x$.  So someone is married to everyone.