# Why can reversing the order of quantifiers in a statement change its truth value?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

The statement
$$\forall x \in \mathcal{R} \exists n \in \mathcal{N} (n>x)$$
Is true, but
$$\exists n \in \mathcal{N} \forall x \in \mathcal{R} (n>x)$$
Is false.

Why does reversing the order of the quantifiers cause the first statement to become false?

Comment: Which value for $n$ would you propose makes $\forall x\in\mathbb R(n>x)$ true?

Comment: Reversing the order of the quantifiers creates an entirely different statement that has nothing to do with the first.  Even though it's a small change notationally, it's a huge one semantically.

Comment: I don't really understand where this question is coming from: order is important - in natural language, in lots of math, and so on. Why **wouldn't** changing the order matter?

Comment: For a more simplistic (and obvious) example, why should changing the order of $1<2$ to become $2<1$ give a different truth value?

Comment: This question has been asked a gazillion times before. Just search for "order of quantifiers".

Comment: Another: [Confused between nested quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64500)

Answer (score 1):

Read them aloud in English, not math.  The important thing is the order $n$ and $x$ are chosen.  In the first, $x$ is chosen first and it says that whatever $x$ is chosen you can find a larger $n$.  $=\lceil x \rceil +1$ will work.  In the second, $n$ is chosen first and has to be larger than any $x$ you can pick.  This is false because you can choose $x=n+1$

Answer (score 0):

Because the second assertion implies $n>n+1$ since $\mathbf N\subset \mathbf R$.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement means : for all real numbers, there exists a natural number **(depending on $x$)** such that $n > x$. (this is clear as we just round up $x$ and add $1$)

The second means: there is a natural number (depending on nothing), such that for all $x$ in the reals we have $n > x$. So all reals must lie below some $n$ (while $x+1$ is **not**).

Answer (score 0):

To recap my comment:  Reversing the order of the quantifiers creates an entirely different statement that has nothing to do with the first. Even though it's a small change notationally, it's a huge one semantically.

---

To expand on it:

$\forall x, \exists n$ means for every $x$, we can find some $n$ that works.  The choice of $n$ may depend on what $x$ is.

$\exists n, \forall x$ means the **same** $n$ works for **all possible** $x$.  This is significantly more restrictive and therefore is not necessarily true when the "$\forall x, \exists n$" version is true.

---

To summarize:

$\forall x, \exists n$ means $n$ can vary based on what $x$ is.

$\exists n, \forall x$ means one value of $n$ has to work for all values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You notice the difference between One for All and All for One? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unus_pro_omnibus,_omnes_pro_uno